# How to append the url to anchor tag inside a div which i got as a json response?

Tags: javascript

I made a ajax to an api and i get the json response

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/key=TMBYhkzfCntMb&limit=20&division=boston',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var a = data.response.deals[0].business.url;
                // Below I get the url of the page with .htm extension
                console.log("link is "+a);
                var mydiv = document.getElementById("empid");
                var aTag = document.createElement('a'); 
                aTag.setAttribute('href', "what i'm supposed to put here ");
                aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
                empid.appendChild(aTag);
            }
        });
```

I have got the value in `a` variable which is a link now and I want to use that url in my anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
aTag.setAttribute('href', a);
```

A more appropriate way to do it will be

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/key=TMBYhkzfCntMb&limit=20&division=boston',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        var a = data.response.deals[0].business.url;
        $('<a />', {
            href:a
        }).text('link text').appendTo('#empid')
    }
});
```

Comment: @Kingisback what is the value of `a`? check the console to see whether there is any error

Comment: hey @Arun P Johny thnx but i want to do this in javascript please

Comment: @Kingisback it is throwing an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined ` because there is no `deals` in `data.response`

Comment: @Kingisback in your page where is this script

Comment: @Kingisback another problem is there is no variable called `empid`, you may have to change it to `mydiv.appendChild(aTag);`

Comment: i have made another file and script tag is written at the top inside the head

Comment: @Kingisback can you give the path of the script file

Comment: @Kingisback also the there is no element with id `empid`

Comment: @Kingisback can you tell what was the mistake

Comment: hey Buddy it was this mydiv.appendChild(aTag) u mentioned it in chat and changed it.Earliar i was keeping the variable a in quotes thats y it was not coming

Comment: @ArunPJohny You are not getting response because you are not authenticated to get the response. Just log the data you get in response and you will see status 401 with authentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` contains the URL you want to redirect, then use this

```
aTag.setAttribute('href', a);
```

Eidt: I think you might also need to append your empId div to body otherwise you won't be able to see it in your HTML. Right now, it is not a part of your document now. To append to document, you can use

```
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```